# front-end-template types decoding issue, value.subarray is not a function

Tags: substrate

#### Intention:

create proxy account with:
[`pub fn create_APNAccount(origin, proxy_type: T::ProxyType, delay: T::BlockNumber, index: u16, APN: [u8; 32])`](https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/7a6ecb87878b6b57c504be74e28bfd6143693130/pallets/claimer/src/lib.rs#L525)

and use `APN: [u8; 32]` and ["Address32": "[u8;32]" of MultiAddress](https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/7a6ecb87878b6b57c504be74e28bfd6143693130/pallets/claimer/src/lib.rs#L998) to store a friendly account name (APN) available for loose coupling to other pallets.

#### function:

This seems to work ok in polkadot js apps with these [types](https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/7a6ecb87878b6b57c504be74e28bfd6143693130/types.json). I can check in storage that the proxy acc is created and that the account is retrievable via it's friendly name using another pallet with [check_name](https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/7a6ecb87878b6b57c504be74e28bfd6143693130/pallets/loose-lookup/src/lib.rs#L60)

#### issue:

I'd like to mimic and extend (involve mapping/outside data viz/etc) this functionality into the front-end-template but i am running into issues with decoding? related to types?, here are types that I have tried:

```
    {
        "Address": "AccountId",
        "LookupSource": "AccountId",
        "APN": "[u8;32]",
        "Name": "[u8;32]",
        "ApnToken": {
          "super_apn": "u32",
          "agency_name": "Vec<u8>"
        },
        "Source": {
          "_enum": {
            "Id": "AccountId",
            "Index": "AccountIndex",
            "Raw": "Vec<u8>",
            "Address32": "[u8;32]",
            "Address20": "[u8;20]"
          }
        }
      }
```

Here are screenshots of each polkadot.js and of the front-end-template. I use the same inputs in both cases.

**js apps:**

[image]

**front-end-template:**

[image]

#### error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding claimer.createApnAccount:: Struct: failed on args: {"proxy_type":"ProxyType","delay":"BlockNumber","index":"u16","APN":"[u8;32]"}:: Struct: failed on APN: [u8;32]:: value.subarray is not a function 

▼ 5 stack frames were expanded.   
createTypeUnsafe
node_modules/@polkadot/types/create/createType.mjs:62
createType
node_modules/@polkadot/types/create/createType.mjs:73
TypeRegistry.createType
node_modules/@polkadot/types/create/registry.mjs:275
extrinsicFn
node_modules/@polkadot/metadata/decorate/extrinsics/createUnchecked.mjs:17
decorated [as createApnAccount]
node_modules/@polkadot/api/base/Decorate.mjs:320   
▲ 5 stack frames were expanded.
signedTx
src/substrate-lib/components/TxButton.js:99 

   96 | const transformed = transformParams(paramFields, inputParams);
   97 | // transformed can be empty parameters
   98 | 
>  99 | const txExecute = transformed
      | ^  100 |   ? api.tx[palletRpc][callable](...transformed)
  101 |   : api.tx[palletRpc][callable]();
  102 |
```

Comment: "Struct: failed on APN: [u8;32]:: value.subarray is not a function" in what context are you getting this? trying to submit the extrinsic? if so, with what parameters? As a way to test SCALE encoding is correctly happening, try this tool: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/codec/

Comment: I would recommend trying a minimal example for your APN data first to ensure the data you are submitting (raw bytes) is transformed as expected

Comment: Yes i get the error, when i am trying to submit the extrinsic with arbitrary values in the APN field. i just created what you [suggested](https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/b3e9445bbba34ef5fadcb32582a4937aab3c7ec2/pallets/claimer/src/lib.rs#L615) same error. this minimal example extrinsic works in js apps even without `apn_value` in the types. But fails in the front-end-template. encoding/decoding on js apps behaves in the same manner as on the SCALE decoder tool. both return a hex representation of the value, something that is missing on the front-end-template